# what are some applications of modern algebraic geometry to conic sections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

The simplest non-trivial example of an algebraic curve is probably a conic section (ellipse, parabola and hyperbola). At the same time, we also know that development in advanced theory can provide new insights even to the most elementary (non-trivial) examples, e.g. Milnor's *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint* contains a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra. Brouwer's fixed point theorem has an elementary statement, but it's far more than the scope of high school-levelled discussion of disks and balls etc.. So now this question naturally arises: what are some applications of the modern theory of algebraic geometry (Grothendieck, Serre, Mumford etc..) to the theory of conic sections, or more generally, to elementary mathematics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) If you take *modern* in a  comprehensive sense, algebraic geometry has certainly thrown a new light on such classical topics as:
1) Pascal's theorem on the mystic hexagram 
([Fulton](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.lsa.umich.edu%2F~wfulton%2FCurveBook.pdf&ei=9bIFVJC2EI3XaJ-egqAL&usg=AFQjCNEY8dT-uu531gXe7MfBuBUTqO0fBg&sig2=mXDt_fpE_z8PHzwjvQGELQ) page 62).
2) [Poncelet's porism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%27s_closure_theorem) on the closing of  polygons inscribed in a conic:  [here](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=26&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CE0QFjAFOBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.univ-pau.fr%2F~jvalles%2FPoncelet-revise.pdf&ei=2qkFVOOAPdDqaO-WgsAE&usg=AFQjCNE6sEIskm0L2w29uzXqARyZVCvWFg&sig2=AjLhffvBhhUWBI3JSayIhA) is a sophisticated modern proof.
3) Steiner's problem ( the rigorous determination of the number, namely 3264, of conics tangent to five given conics) can be solved  by using modern intersection theory  . Here is a [survey](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CJgBEBYwEA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmat.uab.es%2F~kock%2Fenumgeom%2Fenum-intersec-expo.pdf&ei=37EFVKmRHsvtaM-pgbAO&usg=AFQjCNHJkWou6ZG-BickWMGiUOo03gkYHA&sig2=diiEgCJOZf0ft2ooLX7ZSg) (in French, alas) .

B) But there are also  really new results, with no classical counterpart, using the arsenal of modern algebraic geometry :  for example [Hartshorne's ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartshorne_ellipse).

Comment: I never know there's a proof to Pascal's theorem by albegraic geometry!